# What order is extraReducers executed, before or after the reducers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

The createSlice in question from redux-toolkit: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice

I'm wondering if the extraReducers are executed before or after the reducers. Or if the order of execution can't be determined.

Here's a contrived example:
Can it be determined what the accumulate value is after a call to increment?

```
const count = createSlice({
  name: 'count',
  initialState: {
    count: 0,
    accumulate: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.count += 1;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addMatcher(
        (action) => {
          return action.type === count.actions['increment'].type;
        },
        (state, action) => {
          state.accumulate += state.count;
        }
      )
  },
});
```

In a normal redux reducer, It's easy to force an order like this:

```
const initialState = {
  count: 0,
  accumulate: 0
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  let { count, accumulate } = state;
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT": {
      count += 1;
    }
  }

  accumulate += count;
  return {
    count,
    accumulate
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It really does not matter. The default case is per documentation only executed if no other case matches, so they can never be executed both.

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#builderadddefaultcase

> builder.addDefaultCase
> Adds a "default case" reducer that is executed if no case reducer and no matcher reducer was executed for this action.

Comment: Yeah. I realised my mistake in the example. What if I use the addMatcher? Does it follow these rules then: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#multiple-case-reducer-execution
Which would mean the reducer is called first, and then the extraReducers are called afterwards (in the order they are defined in)

Comment: Yes, those rules apply both for createSlice and createReducer